# Edit Windows Terminal Settings via GUI

Tags: windows-11

How can I edit the settings/profiles for Windows Terminal from their settings gui page.  Whenever I try to open settings, it opens in VSCode.  I tried removing the file association for .json files, and now it asks what I want to open it in.

How can I make it open in Windows Terminal?

Comment: The settings are a .json file for Windows Terminal.  What settings dialog are you expecting exactly?

Comment: @Ramhound Like this image https://i3g4v6w8.stackpathcdn.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/02/change-font-global-windows-terminal-settingsjson.jpg

Comment: Have you tried to uninstall Windows Terminal then reinstall it?

Comment: I never figured out the answer to this question, and it seems the behavior is inconstent. On one recent clean install in Aug 2022, my WIndows Terminal settings UI immediately was working (it never went to JSON), but I clean installed again, and this time it goes immediately to JSON no matter how many times I try.

Answer (score 1):

I think I figured it out. When I did a clean install of Windows 11 in Aug 2022, it came with Windows terminal, and when I tried settings it went immediately to JSON and not to any UI.

However, I then went to Microsoft Store app, and looked for Windows terminal, and there were two buttons: Open and Update, which suggests that I had an outdated version. I clicked update, and it installed a newer version, and when I opened windows terminal again, Settings now went to a UI and not to JSON.